# How to load data to an already loaded view?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I have a little project, where i use codeigniter, jquery and bootstrap.

I have "Startsite" where the user have to say:

Option 1: Edit project

Option 2: Create project

I think it is useful to show my Controller as first:

In the construct method i load all models, in the index i load data to all dropdowns in my "startsite", in saveProject i save my created project and the method i have a issue is editProject. Look here:

```
class projekt extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('html');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->model('projektklassen_model'); 
    $this->load->model('kundengruppen_model');
    $this->load->model('produktgruppen_model'); 
    $this->load->model('ablehnungsgrund_model'); 
    $this->load->model('absatzregion_model'); 
    $this->load->model('anfragetyp_model'); 
    $this->load->model('businessunit_model'); 
    $this->load->model('endkundeOEM_model'); 
    $this->load->model('lieferanten_model'); 
    $this->load->model('prozentverteilungEOP_model'); 
    $this->load->model('prozentverteilungSOP_model');
    $this->load->model('realisierungsstatus_model');  
    $this->load->model('gsmbereich_model');
    $this->load->model('firma_model');
    $this->load->model('projekt_model');
}

public function index()
{           
    $data['projektklassen'] = $this->projektklassen_model->getProjektklassen();
    $data['kundengruppen'] = $this->kundengruppen_model->getKundengruppen();
    $data['produktgruppen'] = $this->produktgruppen_model->getProduktgruppen();
    $data['ablehnungsgruende'] = $this->ablehnungsgrund_model->getAblehnungsgruende();
    $data['absatzregionen'] = $this->absatzregion_model->getAbsatzregionen();
    $data['anfragetypen'] = $this->anfragetyp_model->getAnfragetypen();
    $data['businessunits'] = $this->businessunit_model->getBusinessunits();
    $data['endkundenOEM'] = $this->endkundeOEM_model->getEndkundenOEM();
    $data['lieferanten'] = $this->lieferanten_model->getLieferanten();
    $data['prozentverteilungenEOP'] = $this->prozentverteilungEOP_model->getProzentverteilungenEOP();
    $data['prozentverteilungenSOP'] = $this->prozentverteilungSOP_model->getProzentverteilungenSOP();
    $data['realisierungsstati'] = $this->realisierungsstatus_model->getRealisierungsstatus();
    $data['gsmbereiche'] = $this->gsmbereich_model->getGSMBereiche();
    $data['firmen'] = $this->firma_model->getFirmen();
    $data['projekte'] = $this->projekt_model->getProjekte();
    $data['preFormVisible'] = true;
    $this->load->view('project2', $data);       
}

function saveProjekt(){      
    if($this->input->post('btGenerate')){
        $pdm = $this->projekt_model->getPDM();
        $this->projekt_model->addprojekt($pdm);                
    }
    redirect('projekt');        
}

function editProjekt(){      
    if($this->input->post('btladeProjekt')){
        $data['proDetails'] = $this->projekt_model->editprojekt();  
        $data['preFormVisible'] = false;
        $this->load->view('project2', $data);           
    }
    redirect('projekt');        
}   }
```

What should happend?
The user choose on the "startsite" to edit an project. He select a project in a dropdown and click an button.
Here the form from the startsite:

```html
<?php echo form_open('projekt/editProjekt', array('name' => 'preform')); ?>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
  <label for='projekt'>Projekt</label>
  <?php echo form_dropdown('projekt', $projekte, '', 'class="form-control" id="projekt"'); ?>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
  <button type="submit" id="btladeProjekt" name="btladeProjekt" value="btladeProjekt" class="btn btn-primary headbutton"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Projekt bearbeiten </button>
 </div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Now the controller method editProject calls a method in the model. I show you:

```
function editprojekt() {
    $serverName = "de-sal-v-sql011"; 
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"NB_Roll_Plan", "UID"=>"s-global_it-bit002", "PWD"=>"\$Ev1danzA\$"); 
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

    $projektID = $this->input->post('projekt');

    $data = array();
    $tsql = "SELECT ProjektID, Projektname, KDGR, Kundenname, ProduktgruppeID, Projektklasse, MABVertrieb, GSMBereich, Ansprechpartner_kunde,ProjektanfrageNR_kunde, 
        Anfragedatum, Abgabedatum_angebot, PDM, übergeordnetePDM, Kommentar, Projektrisiken from Projekt WHERE ProjektID = ? ORDER BY Projektname ASC";  
    $var = array($projektID);

    $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, $var);
    if($query != false){
        while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
            $data['ProjektID'] = $row['ProjektID'];
            $data['Projektname'] = $row['Projektname'];
            $data['KDGR'] = $row['KDGR'];
            $data['Kundenname'] = $row['Kundenname'];
            $data['ProduktgruppeID'] = $row['ProduktgruppeID'];
            $data['Projektklasse'] = $row['Projektklasse'];
            $data['MABVertrieb'] = $row['MABVertrieb'];
            $data['GSMBereich'] = $row['GSMBereich'];
            $data['Ansprechpartner_kunde'] = $row['Ansprechpartner_kunde'];
            $data['ProjektanfrageNR_kunde'] = $row['ProjektanfrageNR_kunde'];
            $data['Anfragedatum'] = $row['Anfragedatum'];
            $data['Abgabedatum_angebot'] = $row['Abgabedatum_angebot'];
            $data['PDM'] = $row['PDM'];
            $data['übergeordnetePDM'] = $row['übergeordnetePDM'];
            $data['Kommentar'] = $row['Kommentar'];
            $data['Projektrisiken'] = $row['Projektrisiken'];               
        }
        sqlsrv_free_stmt($query);       
    }else{
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }   
    return $data;       
}
```

Now i want to display the returned data in the view, but when i try this nothing happens.

```html
<?php
       if(isset($proDetails)){
        echo "test";
        echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' id='proname' name='proname' value='".$proDetails->ProjektID."'/>";
       }else{
        echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' id='proname' name='proname'>";
       }
      ?>
```

What did i miss? Thx in advance

Comment: why dnt implement ajax ?

Comment: what you mean? i have thought in codeigniter the best practice way is to go with controller and model? Is a mixed setup good?

Comment: please `print_r($this->projekt_model->editprojekt())` and show me

Comment: i see nothing in the console, also when i try print_r("test") in the index method. The index method will be called because the dropdowns are filled. But i'am not able to write something to the console

Comment: please call also `$data['proDetails'] = $this->projekt_model->editprojekt();`  in `index` method and let me know

Comment: What is the result you get if you do `var_dump($data['proDetails'])` before loading the view in`editProjekt()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I think I have understand what is you required @JamesnxD. You can  load the all the drop down in a view and the edit form in another view do like this

```
$this->load->view('front/dropdown');
$this->load->view('front/editform',$data);
$this->load->view('front/front_footer');
```

Comment: thank you for you answer, but just to clarify my goal. My view is loaded with all dropdowns and then the user want to load data based on a projektID. The presentation of the data should be in the same view. Perhaps i don't understand the answer, but when i load 2 different views i am not in the same view or?

Answer (score 0):

some change your model function and add a param.

```
function editprojekt($proID) {
    $projektID = $proID
}
```

and change your `index` method

```
public function index($proID = '') {
    if($proID) {
       $data['proDetails'] = $this->projekt_model->editprojekt($proID);
    } else {
      $data['proDetails'] = false;
    }
}
```

Finally when you edit content you call `projekt/index/12` (12 = projektID) in browser url

Comment: please call also `$data['proDetails'] = $this->projekt_model->editprojekt();` in `index` method and let me know

Comment: then it works. I have to say that i changed in the model the where clause of the query to fixed id. because in index method i have no submit on the form which gives the id.

Comment: in the view the $proDetails is correctly set yes. But the problem is, that i need it in the editprojekt() method because here the submit button post the projectID which i need in the model to have a correct where clause in my query. Now i have a fixed where clause (projectID = 1) because i changed it. Otherwise it is not possible to try the "$this->projekt_model->editprojekt();" in the index function.

Comment: i have final edited my answer. please follow. if any confusion please let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126213/discussion-between-razibalmamun-and-jamesnxd).

Answer (score 0):

you know that you can use array to load `helper`, `model` and `library`

```
$this->load->helper(array('html', 'url', 'form'));
$this->load->model(array('projektklassen_model', 'kundengruppen_model', 'produktgruppen_model', 'ablehnungsgrund_model','absatzregion_model','anfragetyp_model','businessunit_model','endkundeOEM_model','lieferanten_model','prozentverteilungEOP_model','prozentverteilungSOP_model','realisierungsstatus_model','gsmbereich_model','firma_model','projekt_model'));
```